# Gradle coverage report with jacoco for a custom test task

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, junit5

I've split my tests into unit & DB test suites using Junit5 tags. 
I created a new test task of called dbTest to run only those test tagged with the `Db` tag.

Looks like this (kotlin-dsl):

```
val dbTest by creating(Test::class) {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            includeTags("db")
        }  
    }
```

Now I'm trying to calculate the coverage of the DB tests but the jacoco report is always empty.

Jacoco creates a non-empty exec file in the `build/jacoco` dir called `dbTest.exec`.
But when running the jacoco test report the resulting report is empty.
I generate the DB report using a custom jacoco report task that looks like this:

```
val jacocoDbTestReport: JacocoReport by creating(JacocoReport::class) {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = true
            html.isEnabled = true
        }
        executionData(file("$buildDir/jacoco/dbTest.exec"))
    }
```

Comment: the `classDirectories` seem to be missing; see [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html).

Comment: You need to add this; You will have to change, at least, the paths or the db related stuff.
```def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Test*.*',
            'android/**/*.*'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(
            dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug",
            excludes: fileFilter
    )
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.from(files([debugTree]))```